# Discord.js 14 Intents

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am curently updating my bot from djs 13 to 14, but i am having some problems with the intents,
this is the intents code from V13 i had

```
let intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);
const client = new Discord.Client({
  autoReconnect: true,
  intents,
});
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.aliases = new Discord.Collection();
```

and this is what i have in V14 now

```
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits } from "discord.js";
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
});
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.aliases = new Discord.Collection();
```

But i am unsucessfull to set the intents using the 32767 i had before, how can i implement that in the new code, i already googled but i am not succesfull to find it out

Comment: What intents do you need?

Comment: Sending messages, reading messages, joining vc channels, speaking in vc channels, that should be it

Comment: Yeah thanks, that resolved my issue, i can continue on updating the rest off the code now